# Setting fixed background images on the sides of page

Tags: css, background-image, css-position

I'm trying to create my page so that there are background images covering the side of the page while having nothing in the center as that's where the content will be. I want these images to stay fixed where they are, even if the user resizes the window so they're off-screen. I know how to at least set up the images but not how to keep them in place.

I think one example I can think of is how http://www.halolz.com/ is set up.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the way this is done is by applying a background image to the HTML body and then placing all the content of the page into a container that's centered on the page.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
         My content
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    background: red; /* change this to your background image */
}

.container {
    background: white;
    width: 400px; /* adjust this to the proper width */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/13xaqh6z/

Comment: I should have mentioned this earlier but this was meant to be (eventually) used on a Joomla page. I was trying to do it on a stand-alone HTML page at the time. I was trying to avoid having one huge image in order to cut down on file size and loading time.